# ChartJS doughnut chart not displaying colours

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I am learning ChartJS and following along this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sE08f4iuOhA). Tried to adapt the code to fit a doughnut chart, but for some reason, the background colours of the chart are not appearing for me. Does anyone know why? Let me know if more information is required.

**file1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1> OUTPUT </h1></br>
    <h2> For 6_BTV-SISPA R1, there were 37425 hits out of 1316368 reads </h2></br></br>
    <div class="container"></br>
        <canvas id="diamondChart1"></canvas></br></br>
    <script src="simplified.js"></br>
    </script></br></br>
        </footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**simplified.js**

```
let myChart1 = document.getElementById("diamondChart1").getContext("2d");
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Courier";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = "#777";


var massPopChart = new Chart(myChart1, {
  type:"doughnut",
  data:{
    labels: ['UniRef90Hello'],
    datasets:[{
      label:'Population',
      data: [7],
      backgroundColour: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)",
      // backgroundColour: [
      //   'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)'
      // ],
      borderWidth:1,
      borderColor:"#777",
      hoverBorderWidth:3,
      hoverBorderColor:"#000"
    }]
  },
  options:{
    title:{
      display:true,
      text:"Diamond Hits from R1",
      fontSize:30
    },
    legend:{
      display:false,
      position:"right",
      labels:{
        fontColor:"#000"
      }
    },
    layout:{
      padding:{
        left:50,
        right:0,
        bottom:0,
        top:0
      }
    },
    tooltips:{
      enabled:true
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `backgroundColor` instead of `backgroundColour`.

> Please consult the [Chart.js v2.6.0](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.6.0/charts/doughnut.html#dataset-properties) documentation for more details. Also note that there exist [newer versions](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) of the Chart.js library.